# В каких браузерах и на каких устройствах проверять адаптивный сайт?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, кроссбраузерность, frontend

Немного занимаюсь в свободное время frontend-ом (по фану) – CSS3, JavaScript, HTML5, адаптив (чтобы сайт "как игрушка" выглядел, перестраивался динамически под размеры и повороты экрана).

Первым шагом я тестирую полученное на различных разрешениях в эмуляторе Google Chrome с помощью "Device Toolbar".

Когда всё готово, долго и муторно проверяю результат по следующему списку:

1. Mac OS X:

   - Google Chrome
   - Safari 11
   - TorBrowser
2. Windows 7, запущенная на VirtualBox под Mac OS X:

   - Google Chrome
   - Mozilla Firefox
   - Opera 45
   - IE 11
3. Android 4:

   - Google Chrome
   - Android Browser
4. SimulatorApp 9, запущенный на Mac OS X:

   - iPhone 4|5|6
   - iPad 2|Pro|Retina

Интересует опыт профессиональных фронтендщиков:

1. Насколько оправдан мой список устройств и браузеров для проверки результатов? Вы бы что-нибудь добавили? Что-нибудь выкинули?
2. Какой workflow у вас? Как проверяете свои наработки? Ведь это целое адище – протестировать свой код в разных браузерах и ОС, **отнимает много времени**.

Comment: Лично я ограничиваюсь проверкой только в фаерфоксе, хроме с разными размерами окна и в IE11: если в них трёх всё нормально, то вероятность поломки где-то ещё считаю слишком малой, чтоб не лениться проверить

Comment: Но ведь есть ещё iOS и его специфика... я уже не говорю про всякие Opera-Mini браузеры.

Comment: Лично я все нужные мне специфики уже помню наизусть и почти всегда могу глядя только на код сказать, заработает ли он в таком-то браузере или нет, возможно поэтому меня можно считать профессионалом)

Comment: Ну и ещё [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) — верный друг и помощник, когда какая-нибудь «специфика» не помнится наизусть)

Comment: @andreymal, слабо верится, что профессиональная разработка качественных кроссбраузерных адаптивных решений может держаться на самоуверенности.

Comment: Зато она может держаться на многолетнем опыте) Я изредка проверяю всё во всех остальных перечисленных вами браузерах (у меня есть виртуалка со специально старым Mac OS X и специально старым Safari, кстати), и всё работает прекрасно - самоуверенность прокатывает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну и да, с graceful degradation, когда мне не лень над этим работать, всё моё способно работать и в Opera Mini 4+, и в IE8, и даже в Netsurf. Не самоуверенность, а опыт) Пока фронтендщик вынужден заглядывать во все браузеры всех ОС после каждого мелкого изменения — он ещё не профессионал.

Comment: Мне казалось, наоборот. Когда разработчик полагается на свой профессионализм вместо формальной проверки результата – он непрофессионал...

Comment: Основной (и нередко единственный) источник ошибок у профессионалов — обычные опечатки. Но для их вылавливания достаточно проверить всё во всех браузерах лишь один раз, когда всё уже будет сделано, а их исправление вряд ли займёт больше нескольких минут. К тому же для защиты от части опечаток есть автодополение в редакторах и многочисленные валидаторы кода. А специфику разных браузеров опытный фронтедщик или помнит (как я), или выпишет в шпаргалку после однократной проверки. (Кстати, по-хорошему всесторонней проверкой должна заниматься команда специально обученных тестировщиков :)

Comment: А вообще некоторые формальные проверки можно частично автоматизировать с помощью, например, Selenium WebDriver -  оно умеет открывать тестируемый сайт с различными параметрами в различных браузерах (при условии, что они установлены в текущей системе), автоматически кликать что-нибудь и ещё по-всякому взаимодействовать по заданной программе, делать скриншотики и всё такое (я писал скрипты для селениума, когда подрабатывал вышеупомянутым тестировщиком)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Дисклеймер: я не фронт-энд разработчик, лишь сочувствующий; все выкладки - ИМХО, подкреплённое набитыми шишками.

**Шаг первый**, подготовительный.

Определите аудиторию сайта, её технические возможности, цель и место посещения. Это позволит примерно понять, в каких условиях люди заходят на сайт и что они от него ждут. Немного примеров навскидку:

- Места: из дома, на работе, в транспорте, на детской площадке, в туалете, свисая с моста на страховке, под дождём на автобусной остановке, в зале ожидания в больнице
- Устройства вывода: десктоп, ноутбук, планшет, телефон, старый телефон, консоль / телевизор, проектор, слуховой или тактильный аппарат
- Устройства ввода: мышь, тачпад, сенсорный экран, мини-пульт, клавиатура, голос
- Софт и настройки: навороченный браузер, упрощённый браузер, боковая панелька (Opera <= 12.x, Vivaldi), фрейм в игре (EVE, например)
- Обстоятельства: отдых (лениво почитывая или играя), работа (справка, переводчик), активность (про мост и страховку - это не шутка), экстренные случаи, нарушения зрения или координации

Поянтно, что одним сайтом покрыть все варианты невозможно и не нужно; многое зависит от тематики и соотвутствующей целевой аудитории. Исходя из этого можно оценить, какие фичи нужны, а чем можно пренебречь, чтобы облегчить разработку.

**Шаг второй**, аналитический.

Всё программирование - это поиск золотой середины между усилиями и результатом. Чем-то в любом случае придётся жертвовать (в 2008-м я положил на алтарь свежие плюшки типа jQuery ради нормальной работы в Opera Mini), и в связи с этим по возможности не надо делать лишнего. Собственно, любая новая фича будет требовать поддержки на разных уровнях: изображения, стили, разметка, скрипты, браузерные тесты.

Отсюда два вопроса:

- Что требуется от дизайна?
- Что от дизайна не требуется?

Постарайтесь максимально формализовать требования к сайту, чтобы их смог понять даже компьютер. Таким требованием может быть "размер гамбургера от 20 до 40 пикселей" или "всплывающее окошко не должно заслонять название элемента", а то и "расстояние от этой ссылки до той кнопки должно уложиться в один свайп по тачпаду". Всё, что такими требованиями не оговорено, будет считаться допустимой погрешностью - и с этим придётся смириться.

**Шаг третий**, кибернетический.

Автоматизируйте всё.

> это целое адище – протестировать свой код в разных браузерах и ОС

Есть сервисы, которые позволяют проверять свои сайты на разных платформах, [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots), например. Все дополнительные фишки платные, но порой хватает и скриншота.

Если подходить более серьёзно - Selenium, есть и обвязки, позволяющие его встроить в юнит-тесты для веб-приложения. Требования с прошлого этапа вполне реально перенести на скрипт и регулярно его запускать. Более того, если есть возможность выделить отдельную машину, Selenium может работать и удалённо, создавая пакеты "логов" на каждый чих.

При наличии автоматизации вопрос проверки в лишнем браузере теряет свою остроту. Сравнение скриноштов позволит увидеть разницу; история изменений - changelog, а видимые косяки перейдут в раздел требований и новых тестов.

Comment: А как быть с мобильными версиями? Лично сталкивался, когда на симуляторе iphone под Mac OS, с одинаковой версией IOS были различия в отображении и в поведении.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если прям всё завязано на строго определённое отображение и поведение, особо ничего не поделать. Искать ферму с тестовыми аппаратами (такие должны быть для тестирования приложений), ну или робота собрать с камерой и стилусом :) Но лучше постараться найти компромисс между возможностями и результатом, а то потратите два года на погоню за ускользающим пикселем - а там уже новый айфон вышел.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Печально, что только на аппарате можно протестить. Вообще там были не какие-то мелкие различия, а очень даже серьезные. Один из примеров: в `angular 2` не срабатывал `ngAfterContentChecked`, пока не тапнут по сайту.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы выкинул:

- Tor browser

  - Этот браузер тоже самое что и firefox.
- Проверять хром на `Windows 7`

  - Не вижу смысла, так как от маковского хрома он ничем не отличается, тогда уж лучше проверять на xp так как там старая версия хрома - 49.

---

Я бы добавил

- UC browser

  - Им еще пользуются все-таки лучше проверить
- Opera mini

  - браузер с плохой поддержкой, если проект серьезный то лучше перенаправлять на так называемую страницу `badbrowser`
- FireFox для мобилы

  - Различий вроде не должно быть, но лучше проверить.
- Edge

  - Новый браузер от microsoft есть небольшие (или большие) отличия от IE. работает только под windows 8.1 и более

---

Поддержку некоторых вещей можно посмотреть здесь: https://caniuse.com

Comment: Неясно, почему нужно убрать IE 11. Ведь адаптивный сайт – не означает "только мобильный сайт". Он должен и на Desktop-ах нормально просматриваться.

Comment: Я убрал, но спорить здесь можно долго я думаю навряд ли остались люди которые сидят на IE 11 хотя я бы сказал браузер не такой уж и плохой каким его называют.

Comment: И ответа про workflow нет. Вот у меня в списке десяток браузеров и Вы добавили ещё 5. И как быть при вёрстке? Проверять каждую фичу в каждом браузере в процессе вёрстки? Или же верстать в одном, а потом тестировать во всех браузерах всю вёрстку целиком, тратя неимоверное количество времени на проверку?

Comment: Опять же говорю поддержку некоторых вещей можно посмотреть здесь: https://caniuse.com . И вам не придется тестить на каждом браузере.

Comment: И потом через некоторое время вы запомните какие фичи в каком браузере работают корректно.

Comment: 1. Я только что проверил – на подопечных сайтах Яндекс.Метрика показывает 15% посетителей на IE11. Не думаю, что этими людьми можно пренебречь.
2. Сайт caniuse.com даёт теоритическое понимание вопроса. На практике он не спасает от проблем адаптивности и кроссбраузерности, потому что есть практические нюансы, которые всплывают в самый последний момент уже при полной проверке готовой вёрстки.

Comment: В хроме на винде шрифты рисуются по-другому и поэтому лучше проверить, не?

Comment: @rugabarbo как я писал ранее в комментах к вопросу, эти "практические нюансы" ловятся ровно один раз и потом выписываются в шпаргалку или запоминаются. В IE11 "нюансов" много, и я бы на вашем месте его не выкидывал